# Sketch subset of $\mathbb{C}$ which satisfies $|z-3-4i|=5$

Tags: complex-numbers, absolute-value

I proceeded by plotting $z$ on the complex plane, and the modulus of $z-3-4i$:

[image]

From this I deduced that: $$\begin{align}&\mathrm{Re}(z)=5\cos\theta+3\\&\mathrm{Im}(z)=(5\sin\theta+4)i\end{align}$$

And hence that: $$\begin{align}z&=\mathrm{Re}(z)+\mathrm{Im}(z)\\&=(5\cos\theta+3)+(5\sin\theta+4)i\end{align}$$

Which may be incorrect.

Regardless, I cannot derive from it the equation of the subset.

Comment: It's just the set of points of the plane having distance $5$ from $3+4i$: in other words, it is a circle whose center is $3+4i$ and radius $5$.

Comment: I see that now, but is mine the correct equation of the circle? i.e. $z=(5\cos\theta+3)+(5\sin\theta+4)i$

Comment: Yes it is correct.